# Migration and you: getting the best answers for everyone

Tags: discussion, migration

After a little discussion between the mods at Seasoned Advice (cooking SE) and us, we've decided we're going to push for a bit more migration between the two sites.

### What this means

- Asking a question on SA that would be better answered by coffee experts will mean the question is migrated here
- Asking a question here that would be better answered by cooking experts ([e.g.](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2356/how-to-make-a-vegetarian-coffee-jelly?noredirect=1)) will be migrated there.
- Everyone gets great answers to their questions

### What does this mean, like, for *me?*

I'm glad you asked! Migration is not possible for non-mods, and us mods can't keep track of everything that goes on, so if you see a question that you think would be better answered by the community at Seasoned Advice, please flag it and use the custom flag reason to indicate that it should be migrated.

If you do this, there's no reason to leave a comment - asking the user to head over to SA directly might result in dupes being asked, creating more hassle for everyone.

Happy flagging!

Comment: I've been wishing/pushing for this for some time -- thank you for succeeding where I had not!

Comment: @hoc_age See http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/2137/1672 for some perspective from the cooking side. Very briefly, I think the important points here that hadn't been established previously are that coffee has a solid track record now and betas can't disappear, that this is a two-way street, and that anything at all controversial can just stay where it is with no need to try to steer people to other sites.

Comment: @Jefromi - I think my comment did not sound as "positive" as I had intended. I think this is good news and will provide mutual benefit for both sites. Looking forward to continued cooperation! :-D

Comment: Apparently questions usually aren't [migrated to or from a beta site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276084/317795). Is that no longer the case?

Comment: @tim I think this only applies to private betas now.

Comment: @fredley Ah ok, got it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Great!

(Posting an answer so the Community user doesn't keep bumping this).

**Are there any guidelines what types of questions we should migrate?**